# Issue with linking out to a site based on an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpart in a SharePoint that's trying to take data from a dropdown box and a text box to create a `URL` that directs the user to a filtered list based on the text box/drop down (basically a pseudo-search function).  I've got the following code:

```js
function Search() {
 var st = document.getElementByID("Searchtxt").value;
 var cd = document.getelementByID("coldropdown").value;
 val url = "";

 if (st != "") {
   if (cd == "Opt1" || cd == "Opt2" || cd == "Opt3" || cd == "Opt4"){
     url = "FilterField1=" + cd + "&FilterValue1=" + st;
     window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx?" + url;
   } else {
     url = "FilterName=" + cd + "&FilterMultiValue=*" + st + "*";
     window.location.href = "website url" + url;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
```

```html
<select id="coldropdown"> 
   <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="Opt3">Option 3Description</option>
   <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
</select> 
<input id="Searchtxt" type="text"/> 
<input id="btnSearch" onclick="Search()" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

Currently, this isn't picking up anything and the button isn't even attempting to navigate out to the page in question without the URL string on the end.  I'm not sure where the JavaScript element is going wrong, and I've attempted to use the `getElementById` to paste the text from the `searchbox` into a paragraph element and it won't do this either, so I had a feeling that my variable declarations are where I'm going wrong - anyone able to confirm or suggest how to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several errors in your code. I have pasted a working version with comments where there used to be errors.

```
<script>

function Search() {
  var st = document.getElementById("Searchtxt").value; // getElementById was mispelled
  var cd = document.getElementById("coldropdown").value;
  var url = ""; // var instead of val

  if (st != "") {
    if (cd == "Opt1" || cd == "Opt2" || cd == "Opt3" || cd == "Opt4") {
      url = "FilterField1=" + cd + "&FilterValue1=" + st;
      window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx?" + url;
    } else {
      url = "FilterName=" + cd + "&FilterMultiValue=*" + st + "*";
      window.location.href = "website url" + url;
    }
  } else { // main if and nested if were both closed improperly
    return false;
  }
} // there was no closing bracket for the function
</script>

Search Field:
<select id="coldropdown">
  <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Opt3">Option 3Description</option>
  <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
</select>
Search Text:
<input id="Searchtxt" type="text" />
<input id="btnSearch" onclick="Search()" type="button" value="Search" />
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k1qaf40c/

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This now works to navigate but I have an issue with a page can't be found, so I'll revisit my URLs.  But thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

u did not close ur if statement properly

and also `getElementById` was not properly spelled

and u write `val url = "";` which shoud be `var`

```
function Search() {
   var st = document.getElementById("Searchtxt").value;
   var cd = document.getElementById("coldropdown").value;
   var url = "";

  if (st != "") {
     if (cd == "Opt1" || cd == "Opt2" || cd == "Opt3" || cd == "Opt4"){
        url = "FilterField1=" + cd + "&FilterValue1=" + st;
        window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx?" + url;
     }
     else {
        url = "FilterName=" + cd + "&FilterMultiValue=*" + st + "*";
        window.location.href = "website url" + url;
     }
  }else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

ur html

```
Search Field: 
<select id="coldropdown"> 
   <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="Opt3">Option 3Description</option>
   <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
</select> 
Search Text: 
<input id="Searchtxt" type="text"/> 
<input id="btnSearch" onclick="Search()" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

hope it will help